# Python: Convert string into date format

Tags: python, string, loops, date

I know this has been asked a few times, but my scenario is a little different... The objective I need to accomplish is to convert a string of digits '20150425' (which happens to be a date), into a date format such as, '2015-04-25'.  I need this because I am trying to compare date objects in my code, but have one variable type represented as a string.

```
Example below:
    date = '20150425' ## want to convert this string to date type format
    # conversion here
    conv_date = '2015-04-25' ## format i want it converted into
```

Hope this is clear.  Should not be difficult, just do not know how to do it.

Comment: Check this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strptime

Comment: Do you actually want to have `date` changed to Date object ? Or you just want string in date format ?

Comment: @ThePavolC I was about to ask this, because depending on the answer to this question, depends on the code

Comment: Yes I do want it into a date object.  I will be comparing it to another date object.  I will edit that above

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
from datetime import datetime
date = '20150425'
date_object = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y%m%d')

date_object
>>> datetime.datetime(2015,4,25,0,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the date strings will always be 8 characters:

```
date = '20150425'
fdate = "{}-{}-{}".format(date[0:4], date[4:6], date[6:]) # 2015-04-25
```

Alternatively, you can go the "heavier" route and use the actual `datetime` class:

```
from datetime import datetime
date = '20150425'
dt = datetime.strptime(date, "%Y%m%d")
dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") # 2015-04-25
```